# Getting the raw SQL query string from the ORM

Tags: cakephp-3.0

How do I get the raw SQL string sent to the server from the ORM? How do I intercept it in order to do custom work?

I want to forward the query to a custom driver. My target is MS SQL Server via NodeJS - from a Linux environment.

But I don't want to reinvent the wheel. I want to reuse the existing SqlServer query builder.

Answer (score 5):

As long as your query is not executed by toArray() or something similar, you can use $q->sql() to retrieve the raw sql query that cakePHP will execute:

```
$q = $this->Model->find('all');
$this->log($q->sql()); // log raw sql query
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$query = $this->find();
debug($query);
```

`$query` is a query object from where you can get the raw SQL expression.